# NEC "MPC 1003C" chip

Tags: components, identification, component-selection

[image][image]I am restoring an old ROTEL turntable and have come across a "NEC MPC1003C" chip, acting (I think) as voltage regulator. I can not find any information on the internet. Does anybody know any info on this chip? Thanks!

[image: C1003 IC]

Comment: What makes you think it's a voltage regulator? Do you have service data, or photos of the chip in-situ for that matter?

Comment: Could you post a photo of this chip?

Comment: I am attaching photo and schematic. Receives DC voltage from rectifying circuit and then it drives the motor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am restoring an old ROTEL turntable and have come across a "NEC MPC1003C" chip [...] I can not find any information on the internet.

There doesn't seem to be much information available anyway, but you need to use the correct part number for the best chance of finding *anything*.

Although written on your schematic as "MPC 1003C", the correct NEC part number of this IC from the 1970s is:

- μPC 1003C

it is sometimes also written as:

- μPC1003C
  (no space between letters and numbers)
- uPC1003C
  (NEC used the small Greek letter "Mu", but that is frequently replaced by the similar-looking small letter "u")
- uPC1003
  (I have read that the original IC was the uPC1003, and that the uPC1003C and uPC1003C2 were later versions)
- UPC1003
  (all capital letters)

  and similar variations.

I can only guess that organisations who wrote "MPC 1003" on their schematics, as in the one you supplied, actually capitalised the Greek letter "Mu" (a capital Greek "Mu" looks like a capital letter "M").

> acting (I think) as voltage regulator

Actually that IC is some kind of servo motor driver - notice the feedback signal from the motor to pin 1 on the IC. It was used in some 1970s (and 1980s?) tape recorders and turntables, to maintain speed control of the motors. You will sometimes find it mentioned on vintage audio forums.

You can try using the part numbers I have given above (perhaps starting with uPC1003) to search for what little information seems to be available. A few of the ICs still appear to be for sale (as "new old stock" / NOS), although production seems to have stopped a long time ago. I didn't find a datasheet, but by using the correct part number in your future searches, you have a chance for more success.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!! You wouldn't know a replacement for it too???

Comment: Dear SamGibson thank you very much for your answer!! Indeed the turntable was built in late 70's-early 80's. Unfortunately so far I haven't found anything on that chip, no matter how I searched for it (1003 alone, pc1003 etc). Thanks again!

Comment: @Kostas - You're welcome :-) You can wait to see if someone else answers your question and then follow the Help Center page about what to do when [someone answers your question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). "*You wouldn't know a replacement for it too?*" They appear to be for sale on [Ebay](http://www.ebay.ie/itm/401296016972) (depending on how much you trust the seller, of course). "*I searched for it (1003 alone, pc1003 etc).*" I recommended you to search for "uPC1003". Example result: https://www.vinylengine.com/turntable_forum/viewtopic.php?t=35365

Comment: Thank you so much. Ordered 2 new ICs on Utsource at $3 each!!!